# Install windows7 on Macbook Air - no sound

Tags: windows-7, mac, audio, drivers, macbook

I installed Windows 7 on Mac book air, but now there is no sound.
I googled similar issues- one of the finds came out that I have to install realtek drivers, which I did, but still the issue persists.

I downloaded the realtek driver from this post: http://www.fixkb.com/2011/05/no-sound-on-macbook-running-windows-7.html
(the solution section).

Here is screenshot from device manager - what is bugging me is you can see there are two entries in the Sound category, one showing a warning sign.

[image]

Can anyone help?

strangely if I use headphones there is sound.

Here is some info on MacBook:

*MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2011)*

ps. this is not speaker issue

pps. I don't use bootcamp the only OS on my computer is Win 7 now.

Comment: Is your Windows 7 32-Bit or 64-Bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** download drivers from anywhere but the manufacturer's website, it is not safe. You can download Windows "Bootcamp" drivers for a MacBook Air here on Apple's site: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macoscomponents

Comment: Yeah but I don't use bootcamp - the only OS on my computer is Windows 7 now

Comment: It still uses Bootcamp drivers whether it's the only OS or not. Trust us, they work :) Get the latest version you can.

Comment: @Kinnectus  I downloaded this: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836?viewlocale=de_DE&locale=de_DE, after running setup I got ERROR: it tells me this version of bootcamps is not intended for my model of computer

Comment: You need to get the right one for your Mac and for the version of Windows  you have installed.

Comment: @Kinnectus do you know how do I choose the right one?

Comment: Edit your question with the Mac age (E.g. MacBook Pro 2013 etc.)

Comment: @Kinnectus you seem to be my last hope I struggle to find the right version

Comment: @Kinnectus Thanks problem solved. I used this table: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016, to select correct version.