# No sound in Windows 7 (MacBook / Bootcamp)

Tags: windows-7, mac, audio, drivers, boot-camp

I have installed Windows 7 on my 2010 model MacBook Pro using Bootcamp.

I *think* everything installed correctly except for some drivers (bluetooth etc) but the main thing that bothers me is that the sound isn't working.

When I look in the `device manager` and look under `sound`, it says the following:

> High definition audio device

It has this listed about 5 times in fact. When I double click on one of them, it says that the device is working properly.

I read that MacBooks typically have Realtek sound cards in them. I downloaded a Realtek driver for Windows 7 (two in fact, alas one didn't appear to be compatible and wouldn't install) and installed it successfully.

However I still have no sound. Even when I go to configure my sound in the control panel (when I have a YouTube video playing) the visualisers (if thats what theyre called?) appear to be moving, as if to suggest that my system can detect the sound, but without anything actually coming out of my speakers.

I've also tried my headphones and had no luck with those either.

Is there anything else I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac laptops have three different audio outputs; the internal speakers, the headphone jack, and the S/PDIF output (a digital fiber-optic connection that is also inside your headphone jack).  Also, the discrete GPU can send audio through the Thunderbolt port, but I don't know if 2010 models have Thunderbolt.  Anyway, only one output can be active at a time.  The wrong one is probably selected in Windows.

To change it, open the Sound control panel.  Under the playback tab, it will show all the output devices available:

[image: Sound control panel]

It should just be a matter of figuring out which one output is going to.  To choose one, just select it and hit the Set Default button.

**NOTE** I would uninstall the Realtek driver you downloaded and just rely on the BootCamp drivers.  Apple has tweaks in them that break if you download a newer vendor driver (like the screen brightness keyboard buttons or volume buttons).

**Also note:**  Look inside your headphone jack to see if there is a red light on in there.  If it's on, it thinks you have a S/PDIF connector plugged in and audio will never work until you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You should never install any Windows system drivers that aren't from Apple on your Mac hardware.

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1246129/install-windows7-on-macbook-air-no-sound?rq=1) on SuperUser.

Answer (score -1):

For your reference, what helped me to solve the problem was to run the Boot Camp Service repair through the Control Panel -> Programs and Features